# What can make this circuit safer and more efficient?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier, mosfet

Thank you for taking the time to review this circuit. I (only 1yr experience, hobbyist) wondered if I could build an auto voltage ranging power supply with the ability to provide higher currents.

The Zener is set at 40V and it take a little over 100ms to reach that voltage. The 75ohm Resistor (R7) sets the current. So the circuit seems to compensate for that power drop.

[image: Auto Voltage Seeking Circuit]

Here is the first 360ms plotting Vout, OpAmpOut, and VoltageSense

[image: Plot1]

And here is the full 5 second plot:

[image: Plot2]

I'm thinking that the Mosfet (650V 5A Rds <1 ohm) will stop voltage transients. I feel like if I place an X1Y2 safety capacitor in the neutral line along with a fuse that my safety concerns might be met.

Though I can think of better choices, (I just couldn't find a spice model for these) I was personally thinking of using the 51N25, though the gm will change the Rf of the Op Amp (lm358)

Is this design efficient and otherwise safe? What major/minor drawbacks come with a circuit like this? Is there a flaw in the design that LTSpice is ignoring? [It does simulate in Def Con 1 for the first few milliseconds]

Edit: The DC output voltage (Vout) is not meant to be isolated as this Vreg would not have any user accessible parts; I intended to build a Pulse Amplitude Modulator to run an AC motor.

My design purpose was originally trying to find a transformerless way to attenuate an AC signal from 120V/60Hz to around 40V [via the PAM circuit]. I deviated from that purpose when I began wondering about a mosfet power supply.

It's taught me a lot about driving mosfets and sensing voltage.

I won't build this design. However, specific suggestions would help to develop my UNDERSTANDING.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  If you want an offline, non-isolated 40 Vdc power supply with a linear regulator, there are easier ways to get there.  If you are trying to reduce power dissipation with a form of a hysteretic regulator, again, there are more simple topologies.

Comment: I've added an EDIT to my post to answer your question of purpose. Along with that, I wanted a Constant Voltage Regulator that can supply whatever power the Mosfet is rated for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it’s not safe with your non-isolated 0Vdc at line voltage. Also your simulation has the wrong voltage. It should be 141% (sqrt(2)) higher. The pre#regulator will exceed temperature ratings by 200% or more and dielectric ratios by the same.  The pre-Reg. Rise time must be much slower than the output risetime to avoid inrush current damage to caps and over-heating the FET.  I could go on, but you ought to try TI’S or AD’s power designer tools instead.

Comment: Note the new edit in my post - I didn't expect isolation. However, this idea of my voltage being 141% higher. I've missed something in my self-education. Why is the voltage that much higher? And can you explain a little about the rise time?

Comment: 120 Vrms has a peak voltage that will charge your caps up to 141% from the peak voltage for an rms sine wave voltage. This peak is reduced by the sag voltage ripple but switching on at peak voltage of around 170V into a low ESR e-cap with a ripple current rating or an ESR rating will definitely cause a large  surge current of V/ESR=I.  So by having a slow risetime EE on the reference voltage means the target current rises slower to reach output voltage. But if you don’t add a triangle noise to the Vref your bang-bang comparator might cause something else to go “ bang”

Answer (score 3):

Safe? I wouldn’t want to touch the output as it is sitting at half mains voltage. In your simulation, measure the voltage between neutral and the 0V output.

Verdict: fine for simulation, but don’t build a real one.

For the purposes of learning, I’d suggest looking at existing designs to see how they solve the problems you raise. Modern TVs have fairly sophisticated power supplies as do PCs. Get a failed device and have a look at the design, the choice of components and the layout. There is much to be learned.

Comment: I understood the non-isolation aspect during the build. I think I meant safe as in won't start on fire, sort of safety. As to other existing designs, do you have one or two schematics in mind for me to analyze?